# Using google_cloud_scheduler_job to schedule batch jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to schedule a batch job using google_cloud_scheduler_job terraform resource.

As per the document https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloud_scheduler_job.html, I see only the following options:

- PubSub target
- HTTP target
- AppEngine target

Any suggestions on how to create a batch job scheduler using google_cloud_scheduler_job? Thanks.

Comment: publish & subscribe is the most flexible.

Comment: What do you define as a "batch job"?  Is this definition what you had in mind? .... https://kb.iu.edu/d/afrx

What kind of compute logic are you trying to execute?

Comment: By batch job, I'm meaning to execute a map reduce job in a yarn cluster

Comment: @Martin, How can publish & subscribe help with running a scheduled batch job? Thanks.

Comment: @Kans you can publish the jobs there and they can be picked up from there... it's alike a message bus.

Answer (score 0):

Let us split the story into two parts.  Let us assume a function ... that when called, will initiate your batch job.  You can write this function in a variety of programming languages .. in this example, we'll assume Node.  In your Node function, you could (for example) call the DataProc Node.js [sumitJob](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/dataproc/0.5.x/v1.JobControllerClient#submitJob) function to instantiate a DataProc job.

Now the question changes from "How do I schedule the execution of my batch job" to "How do I schedule the execution of a function (which executes the batch job)".  And here is where the combination of Google Cloud Scheduler and Google Cloud Functions comes into play.  [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) allows you to write a code function which is externally triggered by an arriving event.  Such an event could be an HTTP request (as WebHook) or a Pub/Sub message.  And where can these events come from?  The answer is [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/).  Once you have created your function, you can define that the function be executed/triggered on a schedule.  And the result of all of this appears to be your desired request.

A tutorial illustrating Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Functions interacting can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).